# iOS sdk and Instagram

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram

Is there a way to open my application back after sharing image to Instagram?

My share to Instagram code:

```
[Utils saveImage:self.pickedImage withName:@"image.igo"];

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0 ,0 , 0, 0);

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.igo"];

NSURL *igImageHookFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath];
self.docFile=[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
self.docFile.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
self.docFile.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: self.descrText forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];

NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://media?id=MEDIA_ID"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
    [self.docFile presentOpenInMenuFromRect: rect    inView: self.view animated: YES ];
}
else {
    [Utils simpleAlertWithTitle:LOC(@"You have not Instagram app in device.") message:nil];
}
```

Now after this opens Instagram app with share screen opened.
I want to go back to my application after tapping on Share button in Instagram app, and get some callback about shared photo (userId, photoUrl , etc...).

Is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
Hope this answer will resolve your query. This will directly opens library folder in Instagram instead of Camera.

        NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL])
        {
            NSURL *videoFilePath = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[request downloadDestinationPath]]]; // Your local path to the video
            NSString *caption = @"Some Preloaded Caption";
            ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
            [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:videoFilePath completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                NSString *escapedString   = [self urlencodedString:videoFilePath.absoluteString];
                NSString *escapedCaption  = [self urlencodedString:caption];
                NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"instagram://library?AssetPath=%@&InstagramCaption=%@",escapedString,escapedCaption]];
                if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
                }
            }];
```

Answer (score 2):

As of yet, there isn't a callback / x-callback support in instagram. The user will need to manually switch back.